# What's the correct apostrophe usage in this case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, apostrophe

I just wrote a response on a meta Stack Exchange site to a question about tag usage and purpose. In that response, I found myself writing the following:

> I hesitate to argue for the tag's (and
>   the questions' that go with it)
>   complete removal.

"Tag" is intentionally singular and "questions" is intentionally plural. Is that the correct way to use the apostrophe on "questions"?

Comment: You simply should not have an apostrophe, at all, on "questions".

Comment: @Joe Blow: If you drop that apostrophe there's no 'possessive' associated with *questions*, which makes the sentence semantically invalid, rather than just non-standard at the lexical level.

Comment: @Fumble -- not really. The sentence is a shambles - the grammar equivalent of those images you can look at two different ways. (Or perhaps, a Rorschach test!!) You're seeing it along the lines of "tag's removal" -and- "question's removal". Right? Rather it's a possessive that happens to be split up by a strange interjection: "argue for the tag's (by the way, those tags have abc and xyz and pqr, which would also be lost) removal".  In the strange interjection there happens to be a plural, end of story. All the answers below, totally rewrite - the correct uber-approach!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a creative application of the apostrophe to avoid re-ordering:

> I hesitate to argue for the complete removal of the tag (and of the questions that go with it).

It's not outright incorrect to apply the apostrophe in order to omit *of*, but it is highly unusual to *qualify* a possessive noun with a clause introduced by *that*, *which*, etc.; I think most would frown on it for possible ambiguity or lack of clarity in other situations. Still, I daresay I'm rather fond.

Comment: Absolutely. OP's sentence may just about be grammatically valid by some reckoning, but it's so *ugly* I don't think any native speaker would use the form with so many 'ancillary' words. Simpler sentences, like *I like Jim's and Bob's haircuts*, just maybe. But not this one, please.

Comment: @Fumble Yeah, I'm not a native speaker. Totally agree that it should be re-worded, but I was curious nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

No need at all for the apostrophe on your word questions

But why not

> I hesitate to argue for the complete
>   removal of the tag and associated
>   questions

or

> I hesitate to argue for the complete
>   removal of the tag and its associated
>   questions

Comment: You're right the sentence really needs to be restructured, but per my comment against OP, it's incorrect to suggest you could just drop the second apostrophe and leave it at that.